# Как сделать, чтобы java web start приложение не использовало кэш?

Tags: javaws, java

По умолчанию Java Web Start приложение использует кэш на локальном компьютере (из application data, т.е. кэш единый для всех браузеров). Но иногда мне требуется, чтобы приложение запускалось полностью с сервера и не проверяло локальных кэшей (при изменении этого самого java web start приложения и его архивов). Как это можно сделать? Как-то поменять jnlp-файл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JNLP файл должен отдаваться сервлетом (или jsp страницей) с обязательно переопределенным методом getLastModified и специальными заголовками:

```
public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
throws ServletException, IOException {  
...  
      long lastModified = System.currentTimeMillis();

      // Установить дату истечения далеко в прошлое  
      response.addHeader("Expires", "Sat, 6 May 1995 12:00:00 GMT");

      // Установить стандартные HTTP/1.1 no-cache заголовки.  
      response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");

      // Установить IE расширенный HTTP/1.1 no-cache заголовок (используя addHeader).  
      response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "post-check=0, pre-check=0");

      // Установить стандартный HTTP/1.0 no-cache заголовок.  
      response.addHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");  
...  
}

//Переопределить метод getLastModified следующим образом
@Override
protected long getLastModified(HttpServletRequest req) {
      return System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```